# Why my LST code for L5 given high temperaure result?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-5, land-surface-temperature

I am using landsat 5 for LST analysis. My major focus is water temperature. I am using the following code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3dfd6eb7af4e01cc9c8cf438dd6f80fd

```
// This example demonstrates the use of the Landsat 5 Collection 2, Level 2 // QA_PIXEL band (CFMask) to mask unwanted pixels.

function maskL5sr(image) {
  // Bit 0 - Fill
  // Bit 1 - Dilated Cloud
  // Bit 2 - Cirrus
  // Bit 3 - Cloud
  // Bit 4 - Cloud Shadow
  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);

  // Replace the original bands with the scaled ones and apply the masks.
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
      .addBands(thermalBands, null, true)
      .updateMask(qaMask)
      .updateMask(saturationMask);
}

// Map the function over one year of data.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2")
                     .filterDate('2005-10-01', '2005-10-31')
                     .map(maskL5sr);
var visParams = 
        {bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'], 
        min: 0,
        max: 3000,
        gamma: 1.4,
};

var composite = collection.median().select(['SR_B1','SR_B2', 'SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','ST_B6','SR_B7'])

var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};
// Display the results.
Map.setCenter(114.1373, 2.715, 12);  // Sarawak
Map.addLayer(composite, visualization);

{var ndvi = composite.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3']).rename('NDVI');
var ndviParams = {min:-0.3679216957905482, max: 0.9170147398943697, palette: ['blue', 'white', 
'green']};
print(ndvi,'ndvi');
Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, 'ndvi');
}



//select thermal band 6(with brightness tempereature), no calculation 
var thermal = composite.select('ST_B6');
var b6Params = {min: 0, max: 65535, palette: ['blue', 'yellow', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(thermal, b6Params, 'thermal');
// find the min and max of NDVI
{
var min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: geometry,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(min, 'min');
var max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(max, 'max');
}


//fractional vegetation
{
var fv =(ndvi.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('FV'); 
print(fv, 'fv');
Map.addLayer(fv);
}

//Emissivity

var a= ee.Number(0.004);
var b= ee.Number(0.986);
var EM=fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');
var imageVisParam3 = {min: -0.3538557931705386, max:0.8775638328424401}
Map.addLayer(EM, imageVisParam3,'EMM');
//LST in Celsius Degree bring -273.15
//NB: In Kelvin don't bring -273.15
var LST = thermal.expression(
'(Tb/(1 + (0.00115* (Tb / 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15', {
 'Tb': thermal.select('ST_B6'),
'Ep': EM.select('EMM')
}).rename('LST');
Map.addLayer(LST, {min: 20.569706944223423, max:29.328077233404645, palette: [
'040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
'0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
'3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
 ]},'LST');
 // export to drive
Export.image.toDrive({image: LST, folder: 'GEE', description: 'LST_Murum_1005', scale: 30, region: geometry});
Export.image.toDrive({image: composite, folder: 'GEE', description: 'Murum_05', scale: 30, region:geometry});
```

So, why my LST code for L5 given high temperaure result?

Comment: Link doesn't work and the code in the question has errors. Please, fix them.

Comment: By the way, you don't need above code for LST determination. You can observe in following link https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LT05_C02_T1_L2 that Band 6 already corresponds to surface temperature. Correction (Kelvin) would be in your code as: `var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);` (not as 'ST_B6.*')

Comment: @xunilk could you help me fix the problem? what is the errors in this code?

Comment: Copy/paste of code in the question is not good and your asset is not available.

Comment: @xunilk could you please check this link https://code.earthengine.google.com/ceee8dbdb69aac7fe6c304bb8f861aa8

Comment: Now, link works as expected. I will edit your question.

Comment: Your code for L5 LST is given high temperature result because you are not considering a whole one year of data but only one month; as it can be observed in 'filterDate' method from your code. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for L5 LST is given high temperature result because you are not considering a whole one year of data but only one month; as it can be observed in 'filterDate' method from your code. On the other hand, you are also considering a median composite for getting this data (so, high temperatures are also contributing to final result per each pixel).

```
.filterDate('2005-10-01', '2005-10-31')
```

So, I considered a complete year in it (link [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/081712b6a82d6f5855391cad3ee4aa1d)) and load the first image on collection (for January, one of coldest month in Sarawak) for corroborating purpose. I also selected a visualization palette for quickly locate coldest areas. After running my corrected version of your code, I got following result. It can be observed that surface temperature inside red circle (point 114.42736, 2.67217) is 19.27011920000001 ºC (see bottom red rectangle in Inspector Tab). Temperature of 24.195486020000033 corresponds to a median composite (defined by you) in the first red rectangle. This is the reason of difference between them. On the other hand, you can also observe that there is only a little difference respect your LST calculation (LST meaning is Land Surface Temperature). However, this calculation has no sense because you have a thermal band with surface temperature. LST is calculated by using brightness temperature with K1, K2 and radiance parameters not provided in this L5 product.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel that your question was answered you can mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you mean by "However, this calculation has no sense because you have a thermal band with surface temperature. LST is calculated by using brightness temperature with K1, K2 and radiance parameters not provided in this L5 product"? Please.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Jhunu for help. About "However, this calculation has no sense because you have a thermal band with surface temperature. LST is calculated by using brightness temperature with K1, K2 and radiance parameters not provided in this L5 product"

Then do you suggest using LST thermal band as it is?